# startService from main activity not working (IntentService)

Tags: java, android

after been searching stackoverflow to see if there was a question to this, there none that helped me on this.

On my main activity I have this:

```
if (GlobalVars.espera == 0)
{
    GlobalVars.espera = 1;
    try
    {
        bgIntent = new Intent(this, Loadscreen.class);
        startService(bgIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        GlobalFunctions.toast_message(context, "nao");
    }           
}
```

When i start the application it should load the intend to work on background but it isn't.

Here is the class of loadscreen:

```
public class Loadscreen extends IntentService{
MainActivity teste;
private static final String intService = "loadscreen";
public Loadscreen()
{
    super(intService);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    teste = new MainActivity ();
    try
    {
        teste.inic();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

and manifest I have put

```
<service android:name=".Loadscreen"></service>
```

on it too, as a child of application

Even that I have the try, it doesn't go into the catch AKA error, but still doesn't go into the class Loadscreen.

Thanks for the help and time

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
teste = new MainActivity (); // assuming MainActivity is a Activity class
```

You are instantiating Activity class which is wrong.

Comment: Well even if I command that, it does nothing, I have put a breakpoit into the line that contains super(intService); and on debug mode it still doesn't go inside it, just from startService(bgIntent); direct to the end of the try

Comment: @user3310091 that's one mistake you made instantiating a activity class

Comment: are you sure this is if condition matches `if (GlobalVars.espera == 0)`??

Comment: Yes they only pass to 1, when it does what i want on the try that is inside the Loadscreen, and it starts at 0 when the program launches

Comment: @user3310091 try logging something in both the if block and check the logcat

Comment: nothing on the logcat, because it will not start the service, when it passes throught the line startService(bgIntent);, does nothing, not even goes to the logcat

Comment: what happens if you log something in if block of activity?.a tleast you should see that. the code for service looks alright

Comment: Problem solved, it was on the XML. Thanks for your time and patient